# deviceready event not firing in phonegap for android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I wrote simple phonegap application for testing `deviceready`:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
<html>
```

**main.js**

```
window.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
  alert("Device is ready");
});
```

But the alert is never firing. I have added the android platform by running

```
$ phonegap platform add android
```

in the app's root directory (the one containing the www folder), but it still didn't solve the problem. I've also read many answers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982728/deviceready-not-working-in-phonegap-application-how-to/8982770), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27865265/cordova-deviceready-not-firing/27865386) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35932059/deviceready-not-firing-in-cordova)) to this problem, but none worked for me. What could the issue be?

**Edit:** Thanks for pointing out the mistake. Changed `deviceReady` to `deviceready`.

Comment: The event name is all lower case, "deviceready"

Comment: Even with `deviceready` it is not working. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: Oh, you didn't import cordova.js

Comment: How do I import cordova.js?

Comment: You can refer the answer posted below for the same.

Comment: And where can I get cordova.js for android? There is one for download [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-js/blob/master/src/) but does this work with android?

Answer (score 1):

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
//**Note:** src is path for cordova.js
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
<html>
```

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
     function onDeviceReady() {
     // Alert
     }
});
```